# Convert Char String of Wide Chars into ASCII

Tags: c

I have UCHAR that contains something such as:

```
61007300640066006a006c006b00610073006a00640066006c00610073006b0064006a0066006100730000000000
```

I want to convert it to the actual string that it should be such as

```
asdfasdf
```

Does C contain a simple function that would grab 2 bytes each time and convert and end on NULL terminator?

Comment: What is your target platform?

Answer (score 2):

On platforms where `wchar_t` is 2 bytes (ie, Windows), you can use [`wcstombs()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte/wcstombs).

Comment: So from my understanding this will take 6100 and convert it to 61?

Comment: @Doritos the wide char representation is platform specific. It will or will not take `(wchar_t)6100` and convert it into `(char)61`. You are assuming a representation for both `wchar_t` and `char`. Anyway, the functions `wcstombs()` or `wcsrtombs()` and family are used to convert a sequence of wide characters to it's narrow representation. Assuming that `wchar_t` has 2 bytes to represent a character - this is also an assumption. `wchat_t` can have any amount of characters and is not very portable.

Comment: It will always be 2 bytes. I am trying to make it support Unicode. So I guess 6100 gets dropped down to 61. But if a unicode char of 0412 comes, will it keep it 0412?

Comment: @Doritos for 6100, yes, since it represents an ASCII character. But for 0412, depending on the current locale, it may get converted to a valid char, or it may get converted to `?`